# Having problems with node and async

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

I'm trying to excute async-waterfall to get api result and save it to json then save it to database,
thats snippet of my code
Please Help!

```
    async.waterfall([
    function getBook(cbAsync) {
      books.search(query, (err, result) => {
        if (err)
          cbAsync(err)
        res.json(result)
      })
    },
    function saveToJson(saveToJsonCb, cbAsync) {
      jsonfile.writeFile(file, result, (err) => {
        if (err)
          cbAsync(err)
      })
    },
    function SaveToDb(saveCb, saveToJsonCb, cbAsync) {
      const book = {
        title: res.body.title,
        authors: [res.body.authors],
        description: res.body.description
      }
      //save the bookInfo to db
      book.save( (err) => {
        if (err)
          cbAsync(err)
        console.log('Book added!')
      })
    }
  ], function asyncComplete(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.warn('Error')
    } else {
      console.info('Task complete with success')
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

The first task only calls the callback if it encounters an error, which in a perfect condition, will never be called.

Note:

1. Every 'task' must call a callback.

2. Make sure that the callback is called **before** each function finishes.

Follow the pattern indicated in the Async Documentation
http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall